# Cardinal of $A^S$ and $A^T$ for $S\subset T$

Tags: set-theory

Let $A,S,T$ be nonzero, infinite sets such that $S\subset T$ and $T-S\neq \emptyset$.    Then it is easy to construct one to one function from $A^S$ into $A^T$, so that $|A^S| \leq |A^T|$.

But how about one to one function from $A^T$ to $A^S$?

If there is such function, we have $|A^S| = |A^T|$ for arbitrary nonempty sets. So intuitively, it should be false. But I wasn't able to actually prove this. Can you give me a guide line for proof or counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a counterexample.
Consider
$A=S=\mathbb{Z}$ and $T=\mathbb{R}$.
Can you proceed it from here? Let me know if you want me to elaborate on this.